# When is a good time to present references, letters of reference, and letters of recommendation?

Tags: united-states, references, recommendation-letter

I don't think I've ever been asked for references or letters of reference before, but I do want to provide them in this particular instance, because they may help me get an offer.

I've read you should only provide letters of recommendation at the time an employer makes an offer. That doesn't really make sense to me, as I would want the letters to increase the chances of getting an offer.

In this particular instance, I've already had an interview, and I am considering providing references and letters of reference along with my thank you email.

Comment: Are your recommendation letters unsealed? or in electronic form? Yes, by all means, use them if you can't run out of them (in other words, if they're unsealed and in an electronic format). But references are a little bit trickier, I would leave them out until the final offer unless your references are chomping at the bit to receive a phone call.

Comment: If your reference is somebody with the connections/reputation to reach out to the company/hiring manager and make a personal recommendation, then have them do that at the outset.

Otherwise, I'd say don't provide them until/unless asked.

Comment: Kaz, not sure if I understand. What outset? When? Why would my reference reach out without being contacted by the hiring manager?

Comment: Pretty obnoxious that someone voted this down. I can NOT think of a reason this is a bad question.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, by all means, use your recommendation letters if you can't run out of them (in other words, if they're unsealed and in an electronic format).

But references are a little bit trickier, I would leave them out until the final offer unless your references are chomping at the bit to receive a phone call (or unless you know the hiring manager already knows the person who's referencing you).

In other words, if you provide a reference this early on in the process, it's supposed to be very good. Make sure your reference is expecting the call. Make sure your reference knows what to say. Remind them by providing that person with a written outline of your shared experience and tell them what job you're applying for.

That being said, do not give out a reference this early on in the process if you're only expecting a standard HR reference check. That's best left for after you've already accepted their offer.